# Use getFilters() from a template

Tags: php, templates, filter, symfony-1.4

I'm not quite familiar with Symfony yet, so may be I'm asking an obvious queston here. I need to find out the value of a session filter (set from Doctrine) in a template. I tried:

```
$sf_user->getFilters();
$sf_params->get('filters');
```

but none of them works. So my question here: how do I access a filter value from a template.
Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about Symfony's form filters?

Comment: yes, I need a form filter value. It's been set from doctrine and I don't know how to access it from a template.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`$sf_user->getAttribute('product.filters', array(), 'admin_module')`;

You need to replace name (`'product.filters'`) and namespace (`'admin_module'`) with the ones you are using.